# nvm npm node versions become unavailable on reopening the terminal

Tags: node.js, macos, terminal, nvm

I tried to install nvm on my. system using this command -

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
>> already installed IN  /Users/usersname/.nvm, trying to update using git
```

On running "nvm -v" I got an output that nvm is not installed so I used following command

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

that loads nvm . Now I can use nvm to install node and other s/w . Now on restarting the terminal I am not able to access nvm or newly installed node version.

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix for this is to manually create an empty ~/.bash_profile file, and then, add these lines to it:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
```